# How to set arraylist = to every match of a regex

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, arraylist

I am trying to get all possible matches into the arraylist Returnvalue, though when group is called on the regexMatcher it returns only the last results.

How do i accomplish getting all matches into a string or array or any other type of variable?

```
while ( regexMatcher.find() ){
if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){
  returnvalue.add(regexMatcher.group());
  Writer.println(returnvalue.add);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `java.util.regex.matcher`?

Comment: Yes, unless there is another way I'm new to this

Comment: Does't that cause a infinite loop(While(regexMatcher.group().length()!=0)?

Comment: @JoelDiaz Yes it will cause an infinite loop - do not do that.

Comment: What input are you testing on? Can you show some more code?

Comment: @JoelDiaz: I wasn't sure about your exact code, so I just made a sample prg on my own which ought to be similar to what you're looking for. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, suppose you had the String `"John writes about this, and John writes about that"` and the pattern `"(John)([^,]*)"`, you wanted to return each match of the pattern in the string as an element of the ArrayList `return Value`.

In this case, there would be 2 such matches, `"John writes about this"` and `"John writes about that"`. If so, the following short program will give exactly that. Try changing the code to suit your needs.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class testCode
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String text = "John writes about this, and John writes about that";
        String patternString1 = "(John)([^,]*)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
        Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        List<String> returnValue= new ArrayList<String>();

        while(regexMatcher.find())
            if(regexMatcher.group().length() != 0)
                returnValue.add(regexMatcher.group());

        for(int i=0; i<returnValue.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(returnValue.get(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John writes about this
John writes about that
```